# Why aren't my path aliases working with TypeScript in a Babel React Native project?

Tags: typescript, react-native, tsconfig

I have an existing project I am migrating over to typescript. This is my file structure:

```
my_app/
├─ app/
│  ├─ lib/
│  │  ├─ api/
│  │  │  ├─ index.ts
├─ config/
│  ├─ config.js
├─ .babelrc
├─ tsconfig.json
```

In `index.ts` I am making this import:

`import CONFIG from 'config/config';`

It was working before I installed typescript. I have the `babel-plugin-module-resolver` installed and my `.bablerc` file was configured like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["."]
    }]
  ]
}
```

When I installed typescript I got this error in index.ts:

`Cannot find module config/config or its corresponding type declarations`

I tried changing the path in `index.ts` to this and the error goes away, so I know it is a path alias issue:

`import CONFIG from '../../../config/config'`

In my `tsconfig.json`, I configured the path like this:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
   "baseUrl": ".",
   "paths": {
      "config/config": ["config/config"]
     }, 
  }
}
```

I read the React Native documentation on migrating over to typescript, read a ton of blogs on the subject, and looked through the typescript documentation and the `babel-plugin-module-resolver` documentation. I've tried many combinations of things including using the `*` character and switching out `.` and `/` here and there. I feel like each example I find is different.

My `.bablerc` currently looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["."],
      "alias": {
        "config/config": "config/config"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Does anything look off to a more trained eye? I thank you greatly in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer from this [blog](https://www.raulmelo.dev/blog/module-resolution-or-import-alias-the-final-guide#:%7E:text=Tip%3A%20If%20you%27re%20using%20VSCode%2C%20usually%20you%27ll%20probably%20need%20to%20restart%20it%20to%20be%20able%20to%20navigate%20these%20aliased%20imports.) towards the bottom. It was very simple, I just had to close and restart vscode for the changes to be detected. Sheesh!